# How to get know if component is rendered using ReuseStrategy using Angular's router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have interesting question about reuseStrategy in angular router.

So imagine that I have component which I want to be "cached" so if I go back to this component using router It is, without creating, ngOnInit and other stuff.
That's cool, and it's working fine.

The problem is - this component have `<video autoplay>` tag in template. Everything is working fine, but when component is "rerendered" using cache from router-strategy there is problem that the  is freezed.
I must click on this video to start playing.

So the question is are there any type of event that I can use to be informed in component that I was loaded from cached/router-strategy way?
If yes I could simple do this:

```
event.subscribe(()=>this.videoElement.nativeElement.play());
```

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router has a [`NavigationEnd` event](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd) that you can hook into.

```
class Cmp {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.videoEl.nativeElement.play()
      });
  }
}
```